# How to add a new field in Inventory Pivot reporting view. Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo-14

I want to add a custom field to the Product Moves reporting in Inventory > Reporting menu.

I try with this code but I got always an undefined value.
What's wrong please?

```
 class stockMoveLine(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'

    categ_id = fields.Many2one('product.category', 'Product Category', readonly=True)
    
        def _query(self, with_clause='', fields={}, groupby='', from_clause=''):
            fields['categ_id'] = ', s.categ_id as categ_id'
            groupby += ', s.categ_id'
            return super(stockMoveLine, self)._query(with_clause, fields, groupby, from_clause)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and/or show the output of the error ? Which are your models ? What is that is "undefined" ?

Comment: @RobyB
when I grouped by categ_id , I got 'undefined' in pivot view , although , I set category for my products.

Comment: You got `undefined` because `categ_id` field is not set. What does the `_query` function do?

Comment: @Ing explain this in the code in your post, not to me and, again, please shre the exact output of the error. (Stacktrace)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the `undefined` because your custom field (`categ_id`) can not hold the data and there is **not** any usage here for the `def _query` function.

I believed you might be thinking this would be the `analysis view` but no this is just the `normal view` of the **model**.

On Pivot to play around with different fields and analysis purposes you can do by this way,

In the `stock.move.line` **object** put the **related** field of `product->product.category` like you did here but just make as the **related** of this and put the `store=True`

and you can add this new `field` in the `pivot` view or use it in the `search` view with that you can use on a `pivot` follow by search **filter or groupby**.